# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime [ASP.NET]

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, visual-studio-2012

I  get the value from the user in a specific format, then I should convert it to DateTime object.

This is my code

```
DateTime dateGreg1 = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

this code is working fine on my computer, but when I copied the project to another computer, this error shows up:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

My question is why the program is running in the original computer, but when I copied it, it did not run?

Is there any configuration that I should do?

I am using Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Have you inspected the variable `startDate` on the other computer? Where does it come from? I suppose that the input is different, the parse call seems OK to me since it is using the invariant culture.

Comment: You are using ParseExact which means that the passed DateTime has to match the format exactly (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact(v=vs.110).aspx). Try using Parse or TryParse instead. I would debug the program to see what value is getting passed first however

Comment: Actually, as "Steve Harris" said: the problem was with date format of the other computer :)

Answer (score 0):

The 'other computer' probably uses a different date format by default, ie US instead of UK.

Comment: That does _not_ matter since `InvariantCulture` is being used as a culture, not `CurrentCulture`.

Comment: Is the culture relevant when the string being parsed is not in the specified format?